# Difference between a post's likes count and the likes data?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I'm seeing a discrepancy between the number of likes reported in the Graph API vs the number of entries in the "data" that has the name and ID of the people who liked a post.

- When I view a certain post on Facebook, I see that it has 5 people who have liked it.
- When I use the Graph API to fetch the post, the "likes" field has a "data" field with 3 entries in it, and a "count" field whose value is 5.
- When I use the Graph API to fetch the likes for the post (eg, {post_id}/likes), I get a "data" field with 5 entries in it (and no "count" field).

Clearly the true answer to how many people have liked the post is 5. But then why is there only 3 entries in the "data" when I fetch the post object?

Here's another example of the same discrepancy:

https://graph.facebook.com/40796308305_10150394134258306 returns data for a post whose "likes/data" only has 1 entry in it, but whose "likes/count" says that there are 3. But https://graph.facebook.com/40796308305_10150394134258306/likes returns "data" with 3 entries. Finding that same entry on Coca-Cola's page finds that there are, in fact, 3 people who have liked it.

Comment: What's also mysterious about this is that if I visit the URLs above directly in my browser, I see all 3 users who liked the post. But if I go at that same object through the Graph API Explorer, I only see one of the 3 likers.

Comment: Okay, so it definitely appears to be a permission thing, but even so it doesn't make sense. If I ask for the post with the first URL above through my browser, I get *all* of the liking users, but if I ask for them using an access token, I only get 1 out of the 3. So, my authenticated user can't see them, but an anonymous user can? That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation of the post object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) doesn't mention that the likes list may be incomplete, and the [documentation of the fql stream table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) explicitly says to use the post object to get the full list, so It's either a bug in the API or in the documentation.

I suspect it may be a deliberate but undesirable "feature" to limit the detailed list for performance reasons, as some posts may have hundreds or even thousands of likes.

It ends up actually causing a huge performance problem as I need to find all posts that have been liked by a particular user, and the only way to do that is to do a separate fetch of likes for each post in the list whose like count is higher than the like list length.

Comment: Also mentioned here: [http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=106876](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=106876)

Answer (score 1):

2 people have their privacy settings set to not show their name to people who are not their friends.

Comment: If this were true, then why do I get to see *all* of those users when I go to the {POST ID}/likes endpoint? I'd think that both endpoints would consistently hide those 2 people.